# How to identify which windows KB patch create impact to Sharepoint 2010...?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, windows-server

One of my client did the Vulnerability test on my sharepoint production box. In the Vulnerability report they have mention the list of missing windows KB patches.

Now i wanted to know how to validate the this windows KB patches. Whether its creating any impact on sharepoint or not.

Please advice me....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For a list of patching levels Dave Coleman maintains a list of http://www.sharepointedutech.com/2010/09/06/sharepoint-server-2010-patch-levels-and-cumulative-updates/

In your SharePoint farm, under System there is a link showing the Upgrading and Patching level for each server, with the KB next to each update, some might be in red, which clearly indicates an update needed. Use that KB number to identify in which Cumulative Update it exists and then you could plan for its installation.

Same KB numbers are also visible in Windows>Control Panel, under System Updates.

Comment: But the list which is provided by the client its not related to sharepoint. Its related to windows 2008 server security. I am worried if any patch will create any bad impact on the sharepoint. then my live site will down. So need to validate each of this patches.

Comment: Regularly no patches have impact on a SharePoint farm. You should plan however before installing updates such as .NET framework, or manipulating IIS Components, etc, but security patches should be fine. My explanation should help you identify which of those patches coincide with those installed by SharePoint. REMEMBER: CUs only replaces (updates) software packages ALREADY installed - all others are ignored!

Answer (score 0):

Very few patches have had a direct, negative impact on SharePoint 2010.  The single patch I can think of that has created a direct impact on 2010 was MS11-100 which a fix was issued for SharePoint in the April 2012 CU.